# Fazer que o botão fique visível em determinado tempo

Tags: java, android, admob

Olá, estou tentando fazer que o botão "**X**" de fechar o anúncio apareça depois de 15 segundos.

Não sei a função correta para isso mais eu fiz em base ao tempo de aparecer anúncios intersticial da admob.

Veja meu código:

```
      MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.ID_APP_ADMOB));
        final LinearLayout adscontainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adsContainer);
        final AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        final Button closeAd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.closeAd);
        final FrameLayout frameAds = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameAds);
        AdView adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        ///tempo contado em milisegundos
        TempoCorrido = new CountDownTimer(15000, 50) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUnitFinished) {
                TempoMilisegundos = millisUnitFinished;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                closeAd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); /// Exibi o botão X
            }
        };
```

**XML**:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/closeAd"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp" />
```

O problema é que não está aparecendo o botão depois dos 15 segundos. Como procede?

Comment: Não entendo porque negativaram minha pergunta e não deixaram nenhum comentário!

Comment: Falta chamar o método  _start()_ depois da criação da tarefa _TempoCorrido_

Comment: Você pode me da um exemplo? Sou iniciante e não manjo de java ainda, fiz essas coisas vendo tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chame o método *start()* depois da criação do objeto e veja se funciona

```
            TempoCorridoX = new CountDownTimer(15000, 50) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            //// nada faz
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                closeAd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); /// Exibi o botão X de fechar o anúncio
            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: Vou testar e posto o resultado!

Comment: Não apareceu o botão, continuou na mesma

Comment: No XML deixe o _Button_ como _visible_. Chamou o método _start()_?

Comment: Conseguir de um jeito aqui, me dê permissão pra eu editar sua resposta e colocar como deu certo.

Comment: Que com que conseguiu. Pode editar.

Comment: Pronto, muito obrigado!